# Exit shell script in error handle function without exiting the terminal

Tags: bash, scripts

I am writing a shell script. That shell script is executed in a `bash` shell inside a terminal. It contains a central error handler function. Please see the following basic demo snippet:

```
function error_exit
{
   echo "Error: ${1:-"Unknown Error"}" 1>&2
   exit 1 # This unfortunately also exits the terminal
}

# lots of lines possibly calling error_exit
cd somewhere || error_exit "cd failed"
rm * || error_exit "rm failed"
# even more lines possibly calling error_exit
```

The error handler function should end the script but should NOT end the terminal. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bash`'s `trap` builtin to spawn a `bash` instance upon the script's exit:

```
trap 'bash' EXIT
```

From `help trap`:

```
trap: trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
    Trap signals and other events.

    Defines and activates handlers to be run when the shell receives signals
    or other conditions.

    ARG is a command to be read and executed when the shell receives the
    signal(s) SIGNAL_SPEC.  If ARG is absent (and a single SIGNAL_SPEC
    is supplied) or `-', each specified signal is reset to its original
    value.  If ARG is the null string each SIGNAL_SPEC is ignored by the
    shell and by the commands it invokes.

    If a SIGNAL_SPEC is EXIT (0) ARG is executed on exit from the shell.
```

So by running `trap 'bash' EXIT`, `bash` will be read and executed when the shell receives the signal EXIT; spawning an interactive shell will consequentially have the effect of preventing the terminal from closing:

```bsh
function error_exit
{
   echo "Error: ${1:-"Unknown Error"}" 1>&2
   exit 1 # This unfortunately also exits the terminal
}

trap 'bash' EXIT
# lots of lines possibly calling error_exit
cd somewhere || error_exit "cd failed"
rm * || error_exit "rm failed"
# even more lines possibly calling error_exit
```